# How can I kill a Pool of workers when one of them completes their task?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am writing a simple bruteforce script and I tried to add multiproessing to make it faster, but I do not know how to write the `callback` function that will terminate the workers when one of them finds the password.

I tried to make global variable that I pass from bruteforce function to the quit function, but no success.

I will post the worker code and bruteforce part. It may be a bit messy, I was just trying things and was doing professional debugging with print statements.

```
class Process:
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.args = args
        self.ncpu = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
        self.pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=self.ncpu)

    def quit(self, result):
        if result:
            self.pool.terminate()

    def run(self, args):
        split = MultiSplit(self.args)
        if not self.args.m:
            split.split()
            for i in range(1, self.ncpu + 1):
                self.pool.apply_async(bruteforce, (args, i), callback=self.quit)
            self.pool.close()
            self.pool.join()
        else:
            bruteforce(args, 0)
```

Here is the `bruteforce` function

```
def bruteforce(args, n):
   in_zip = args.input
   if not args.m:
       wl = "/home/kuskus/Desktop/ZyBR/testing/wordlists/%d.txt" % n
   elif n == 0:
       wl = args.wordlist
   print(pyzipper.AESZipFile(in_zip))
   found = False
   global password
   with pyzipper.AESZipFile(in_zip) as zf:
       with open(wl) as wordlist:
           for line in wordlist:
               password = line.strip('\n')
               if not found:
                   try:
                       zf.pwd = str.encode(password)
                       zf.extractall('./')
                       print("password found: %s" % password)
                       return
                   except Exception:
                       if args.q:
                           pass
                       else:
                           print(password)
```

My idea was to somehow return the found variable from `bruteforce` function to the `callback` function, but I do not think that would work since I need to do it 4 times.

Comment: Are you aware of [`pool.terminate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.terminate)?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: once one of the processes returns, kill the others by terminating the pool.

Comment: Oh I see. If you read the code, you can see I am using pool.terminate. The issue is it terminates when any worker finishes. But I want it to terminate only if one of the workers returns password and not when it reaches end of wordlist

Comment: Oh, I didn't see it in there. What I'd do is have the main process handle the pool and wait for a reply (you need to look into the async version of the functions), then kill the pool once the first reply comes

Comment: That is something similar to what I have on my mind. But I cannot think of a way how to handle it. I would probably need to pass something from `bruteforce` e.g. the `password` variable into the corresponding worker